# Render few values using {{#each}} helper

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

I am using  {{each}} helper of handlebar in my ember application to render hourly values in divs. Problem is I am getting values for all hours from 0 to 23. I just want to render values from hour 9 to 19. To render all we can write like this

```
{{#each hrVal in data.hourlyValues}}
<div>{{hrVal}}</div>
{{/each}}
```

data.hourlyValues = [0,0,3,4,2.....23 values]

Is there any way other than writing my custom helper to achieve the result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Handlebars templates are logic-less, so the way you do this is by using a computed property on your controller.

```
filteredHourValues: Ember.computed.filter('data.hourlyValues', function(value) {
    return (value >= 9 && value <= 19);
})
```

Then use the new property in your template.

```
{{#each hrVal in filteredHourValues}}
    <div>{{hrVal}}</div>
{{/each}}
```

[Here's the computed.filter documentation](http://emberjs.com/api/#method_computed_filter) in case you need it.